# Check if column contains value from a list and assign that value to new column

Tags: r, data.table

I have a list that contains patterns to find. Then I have a data.table in which I want to find if the value contains any ot the patterns then assign that value to a new column:

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr)
base_patters <- c("pat1","pat2","pat3")

transformations <- data.table(mynames = c("HI_pat1_jo","A2_a4_pat1_LN","pat3_LN")
)

for( patt in base_patters){
  transformations[stringr::str_detect(transformations[, mynames], patt), pattern := patt]  
}
```

I have solved (as you see) with a for loop but I am looking for a more efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paste the `base_patters` together and use `str_extract` to extract any pattern present in `mynames`.

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr)

transformations[,pattern := str_extract(mynames,str_c(base_patters,collapse = "|"))]

#         mynames pattern
#1:    HI_pat1_jo    pat1
#2: A2_a4_pat1_LN    pat1
#3:       pat3_LN    pat3
```